# Undefined property: > stdClass error when using date type column on Laravel. How can I solve it?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to insert data (date type data) through a form in a web service built with Laravel.

the solicitacoes.blade.php code:

```
    @extends('layout.app', ["current" => "solicitacaos"])

@section('body')

<div class="container">
<div class="card-border">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Solicitações</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th> Professor
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Criação
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Data Solicitação
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Nome do Produto
                        </th> 
                        <th>
                            Observações
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Ação
                        </th>           

                    </tr>

                    @foreach($sols as $sol)

                    @php

                        dd($sol)

                    @endphp


                    <tr>
                        <td> {{$sol->nome_professor}}
                        </td>
                        <td> {{$sol->criacao}}
                        </td>
                        <td> {{dd($sol)}}
                        </td>
                        <td> {{$sol->nome_produto}}
                        </td>
                        <td> {{$sol->observacao}}
                        </td>
                        <td> {{$sol->status}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/solicitacao/apagar/{{$sol->id}}" class="btn btn-sn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
            </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The error is on the line " {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($sol->solicitacao_data->from_date)->format('d/m/Y')}} "

Even if I change the line " {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($sol->solicitacao_data->from_date)->format('d/m/Y')}} " to " {{$sol->solicitacao_data}} ", I still getting the same error.

The controler code is:

```
$date_sol = new DateTime();
$date_sol = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y",$request->input('solicitacao_data'));

$sol->solicitacao_data = $date_sol;

$sol->save();
```

I am inserting '25/2/2020', but I get the following error:

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Undefined property:
>   stdClass::$solicitacao_data (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\workflow-novo\resources\views\solicitacoes.blade.php)

The database table is created through migrations, as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSolicitacaosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('solicitacaos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('id_users')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_users')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->bigInteger('id_produto')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_produto')->references('id')->on('produtos');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->string('observacao');
            $table->date('solicitacao_data');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('solicitacaos');
    }
}
```

I need to store and recover the date using Laravel. How can I make it without the error above?

**I have noticed that if I try to save the time, the database saving does not work properly. For example, the following code:

```
$date_sol = Carbon::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s","20/12/2020 01:00:00");

$sol->solicitacao_data = $date_sol;
```

stores the following data on solicitacao_data column.

```
MariaDB [login]> select * from solicitacaos;
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----
----------------+---------------------+
| id | id_users | id_produto | status     | observacao | solicitacao_data | crea
ted_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----
----------------+---------------------+
| 24 |        1 |          1 | Em Análise | blabla     | 2020-12-20       | 2019
-12-30 23:47:52 | 2019-12-30 23:47:52 |
| 25 |        1 |          1 | Em Análise | blabla     | 2020-12-20       | 2019
-12-31 01:22:50 | 2019-12-31 01:22:50 |
| 26 |        1 |          1 | Em Análise | blabla     | 2020-12-20       | 2019
-12-31 01:23:08 | 2019-12-31 01:23:08 |
| 27 |        1 |          1 | Em Análise | blabla     | 2020-12-20       | 2019
-12-31 01:27:33 | 2019-12-31 01:27:33 |
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----
----------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Note that only the date is being stored.

I have executed the command dd($sol) in the solicitacao.blade.php I have got the following:

```
{#341 ▼
  +"id": 1
  +"status": "Em Análise"
  +"nome_professor": "Olavo"
  +"criacao": "2019-12-31 02:08:11"
  +"nome_produto": "Cadeira"
  +"observacao": "awdcasd"
}
```

Even though the table has the columns I have shown before.

```
MariaDB [login]> select * from solicitacaos;
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----
----------------+---------------------+
| id | id_users | id_produto | status     | observacao | solicitacao_data | crea
ted_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----
----------------+---------------------+
| 24 |        1 |          1 | Em Análise | blabla     | 2020-12-20       | 2019
-12-30 23:47:52 | 2019-12-30 23:47:52 |
| 25 |        1 |          1 | Em Análise | blabla     | 2020-12-20       | 2019
-12-31 01:22:50 | 2019-12-31 01:22:50 |
| 26 |        1 |          1 | Em Análise | blabla     | 2020-12-20       | 2019
-12-31 01:23:08 | 2019-12-31 01:23:08 |
| 27 |        1 |          1 | Em Análise | blabla     | 2020-12-20       | 2019
-12-31 01:27:33 | 2019-12-31 01:27:33 |
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----
----------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: please put your all controller coed

Comment: I have added some code to the question.

Comment: you need to provide the controller method that returns that view so we can see how you are retrieving the data since you are not using a Model

Comment: It is there. I say "the controler code is:" and the "solicitacoes.blade.php" code is the one that retrieves the data. It all there.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Error message, you are call the attributes named `$solicitacao_data` in the solicitacoes.blade.php,

Your stdClass `$sol` have no attribute `solicitacao_data`, so the error occurs.

Make sure to select the column `solicitacao_data` by query,

and don't put this field in model's `$hidden`.

Comment: I am not using "->$solicitacao_data" anywhere.

Comment: As the code I have posted above, I am using "$sol->solicitacao_data = $date_sol;"

Comment: I got what you mean. I have posted the solicitacoes.blade.php, where it uses "$sol->solicitacao_data->from_date".

Comment: It is probably where the error is. I do not know how to solve it, however.

Comment: It saves the information in the database through the controler then when the data is to be read, the error occurs.

Comment: @Siqueira In your table `solicitacao_data` is just a date field, however, in your view you call the `from_date` from `solicitacao_data`, `$sol->solicitacao_data->from_date`

Comment: Even if I call $sol->solicitacao_data, I get the same error.

Comment: @Siqueira In the error message. it will print the error message line number, check that line number

Comment: It points to this line:                         <td> {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($sol->solicitacao_data)}}
I have wrote it in the question description.

Comment: @Siqueira I think you need to `dd($sol)` and post what `$sol` really is.

Comment: dont get it. I am posting what sol really is, through the $sol->save(); command.

Comment: I have got what you meant by using dd($sol) ... the column "solicitacao_data is missing".. why?

Comment: @Siqueira Maybe you add `solicitacao_data` in hidden field. May be you don't select it. plz post your action code which render the solicitacoes.blade.php.

Comment: I am selecting all the table.

Comment: I have added the entire code of the solicitacoes.blade.php

Comment: Yes ... I am not used to program with these technologies and I forgot that the table presents values of a query. You are right, there is a selection of columns in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_sol = new DateTime();
    $date_sol = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y",$request->input('solicitacao_data'));

    $sol->solicitacao_data = $date_sol;

    $sol->save();
```

According to above code, there must be an input with name "solicitacao_data" on your blade file for
**$date_sol = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y",$request->input('solicitacao_data'));**
to work.